# Sharing unit testing fixtures

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, fixtures

I'm writing unit tests for a project (written in PHP, using PHPUnit) that have its entire environment (loaded components, events, configuration, cache, per-environment singletons, etc) held in an object which all the components use to interact with each other (using a mediator pattern).

In order to make the unit tests run faster, I'm sharing the environment object and some other objects (for example, in my test case for view object [as in the V of MVC], the view manager object [which acts as a factory for view objects and responsible for the actual rendering]) among tests in the same test case (using PHPUnit's `setUpBeforeClass()` and static properties).

Even though, to the best of my knowledge, the objects I share shouldn't effect the integrity of the tests (in the views case, for example, the environment and view manager object are shared, but a separate view object is created for every test - which is the object that's actually being tested by the test case), it just feels increasingly wrong to me.

I would prefer it if each test used a completely isolated environment and couldn't effect other tests in the same test case in any way. However, that would make the tests run much slower and it feels like a big price for something that I can't really pinpoint the downside of and mainly just "feels wrong".

What do you think? Can you pinpoint any downsides so I can convince myself its worth the longer execution time? Or am I just over reacting and its completely fine?

Comment: cant you define some "test profiles"? so you have to run all the tests all the time? This way you would run the "full tests" profile maybe once a day, and use a smaller, more manageable profile for the current work-in-progress

Comment: Sorry - I kinda forgot to give the bounty. I think its just gone when it expires and no-one gets it? I'm starting another one and giving to to Willie, but I wish I could split it as all the answers are very useful. Thanks all! *update* it seems like I can only give the bounty after 24 hours - hope I won't forget about it that time :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like writing "normal" code, when you write test cases, it's fine to rely on knowledge of how fixture objects work.

If a given factory method is documented as generating new instances every time, then I see only downside in creating the factory method anew each time, especially if the factory creation is itself expensive.

It helps to keep in mind a key goal around writing unit tests. You want to know within 5-10 minutes whether you broke the build. That way you can go out to lunch, go to a meeting, go home, etc. after you get the "all clear". If you know that some part of the fixture is reusable without creating interactions, then you should use that knowledge to make your tests even more comprehensive within that 5-10 minute window. I understand the purist impulse here, but it buys you nothing in terms of test independence, and it unnecessarily limits what your test suite will accomplish for you.

Answer (score 5):

I share your feelings so maybe i just state my goals and my solution when i faced that issue:

- Devs should have a test suite that runs very very fast
- At least single test cases should execute in less than a second
- I **really** want to be sure i don't have interdependencies in my test cases

I'm going to assume you have a Continuous Integration Server running. If not a cronjob might do but consider setting up [jenkins](http://jenkins-php.org/), it's [really really easy](http://edorian.posterous.com/setting-up-jenkins-for-php-projects).

---

#### For normal usage:

Just share as much fixtures as you need to get the speed you need. It might not be pretty and there might be better solutions along the way but if you have something that is expensive to create just do it once.

I'd suggest helper methods `getFoo() { if(!self::$foo) .... create ... return $foo;}` over `setUpBeforeClass` because it can make sharing easier but mainly because of the following point.

#### Once a night:

Run your test suite with --process-isolation and in that bootstrap recreate your complete database and everything.

It might run 6 hours (disable code coverage for that!) but how cares. Your fixtures will be recreated for every single test case since it's a new php process and the static vars don't exist.

---

Using this way you can be sure that you don't have created dependent once a day. Thats good enough to remember what you did (and you can run with --filter and --process-isolation if you need to fix something).

Comment: I didn't quite understand What's the difference between `setUpBeforeClass` and the getter function you suggested. The only difference I see is that the getter method will only create the object(s) when its requested for the first time, while `setUpBeforeClass` always creates them. What difference does it make in regards to the 'Once a night' point?

Comment: And thanks for the jenkins suggestion. I wanted to give [Bitten](http://bitten.edgewall.org/) a try since it should work nicely along with [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) (which I already use for quite some time and I'm very happy with it), but it seems like its not quite stable enough yet, so I might go with jenkins instead

Comment: @shesek Sorry for taking some time to answers. Was out of town. In short: Those helper methods would make it easier help using the fixtures across different test classes in case you need that at some point in time. If they are really expensive to create maybe you really need only one for your suite? If that doesn't quite answer your question maybe i can build up some more examples

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is blasphemous, but if you can still manage a significant threshold of code coverage and you can also guarantee that no state pollution can exist (and that is your real issue -- are you making sure that each test will not be effected by the data left over from the test before), I see no problem with leaving things the way they are.

Let the tests run quickly, and when a bug is found (which is inevitable in integration testing) then you have reason to invest the time in localizing one particular test or set of tests. If you have a toolkit which works for the general case, however, I would leave it as is.